# ClassVisitor's methods are not called in asm

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, javaagents

I'm using asm 9.2 jars to instrument methods.

Below is my code.

```
ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(classBytes);
ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr, ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS | ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
            
EnterExitClassAdapter ca = new EnterExitClassAdapter(cw, config, aspects);
cr.accept(cw, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
return cw.toByteArray();
```

```
public class EnterExitClassAdapter extends ClassVisitor {

    Type classType;
    String[] interfaces;

    public EnterExitClassAdapter(ClassVisitor cv, Config config,
            Aspect[] aspects) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM9, cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(int version, int access, String name, String signature,
        String superName, String[] interfaces) {

        super.visit(version, access, name, signature, superName, interfaces);
        classType = Type.getType("L" + name + ";");
        this.interfaces = interfaces;
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc,
            String signature, String[] exceptions) {
            
        //My code here.
        
    }
}
```

The methods in EnterExitClassAdapter is not called (i.e visit and visitMethod) except its constructor.
I'm running a sample application with java 8.

I'm new to asm. Almost spent more than 2 days on this. But still don't know what I'm missing.

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `cr.accept(cv, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);` instead of `cr.accept(cw, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);`?

Comment: You have to pass your visitor to the `accept` method, i.e. `ca` rather than `cw`.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Thanks, you saved my day.

Comment: @Holger Thanks a lot. I missed it. It works now.